# File Transfer Plugin is behaving asynchronously while uploading video and downloading from server

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, file-transfer

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

```
document.getElementById('uploadVideo').addEventListener("click", onUploadVideo);

// ---------------------------
// Upload Video Code
// ---------------------------

function onUploadVideo() {

    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { 
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.VIDEO,
        allowEdit: true
     });
  
     function onSuccess(videoUri) {

      // File Upload
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "video";
        options.fileName = videoUri.substr(videoUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        options.mimeType = "video/mp4";
        options.httpMethod  = "POST";
        options.chunkedMode = false; 

        options.headers = {'X-CSRF-Token': localStorage.getItem('u:token')};
        var params = {}; 
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";
        options.params = params;

        alert("URL of Video is : " + videoUri);
        alert("FileName of Video is : " +  options.fileName);
        alert("FileKey of Video is : " + options.fileKey);
        alert("mimeType is : " + options.mimeType);

        // Give your IP Address and PORT Number
        **var uri = encodeURI("http://192.168.43.130:8081/extractAudio.php");**
        // var uri = encodeURI("http://192.168.1.5:443/uploadvideo.php");
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(videoUri,uri, function(result){
            alert('successfully uploaded ' + result.response);
          }, 
          
          function(error){
            alert('error : ' + JSON.stringify(error));
          }, 
        options);
        
        // ---------------------------
        // Progress Code
        // ---------------------------
        
        var statusDom;
        statusDom = document.getElementById('status');

        ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {

            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
                statusDom.innerHTML = perc + "% loaded...";
                console.log(perc);

                } else {
                        if(statusDom.innerHTML == "") {
                        statusDom.innerHTML = "Loading";
                } else {
                        statusDom.innerHTML += ".";
                }

                }
            };

        
        var download_URL = encodeURI("http://192.168.43.130:8081/upload/Dance.mp3");
        // var download_URL = encodeURI("http://192.168.1.5:443/upload/sample.mp3");
        var fileURL =  "*******************";
        // var fileURL =  "********************";

        ft.download(download_URL, fileURL, 

          function(result) {
            alert("download complete: " + result.toURL());
          },

          function(error) {
            alert("download error source " + error.source);
            alert("download error target " + error.target);
            alert("download error code" + error.code);
          },

          false, {

            headers: {
               "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
            }

         }

      );

    }

     function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
     }

}
```

}

// download_URL is executing first, this is why I am unable to download the sample.mp3 file as it is not on the server. But once if I do the same with the same file it downloads the mp3 file as it already in the server. summarising the points it trying to download before finishing uploading. I need to upload first and then download the mp3 file. Can someone help me with this.